# How to see logs of running robot script?

Tags: robotframework

The robot scripts when ran on RIDE, generate output.xml, report.html etc files, once run is over.

Is there any way available to view logs when script is still running? (When I use pause on failure)
Also some times I had to Stop/Abort the run in middle, and no logs are generated in such cases.

Kindly help,

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should look into listener interface. I think it will do what you need: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface

Comment: Maybe my answer here helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/73361421/2235381

Answer (score 2):

As for first part — RIDE runs tests adding own [listener](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface), providing more verboseness of the output and pausing/resuming functionality.The easiest thing is to run tests not from RIDE, but from console using [robot/pybot](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-robot-and-rebot-scripts) script. In this case much less logs are written to output (though it doesn't provide pause/resume functionality).

For second part — robot (RIDE starts robot script — you can see it in execution log: `command: pybot.bat...`) generates `output.xml` file not after but *during* execution, so generated `output.xml` is not valid until test is finished. After normal execution rebot tool generating log.html automatically. So generally it's possible to take following steps:

1. "Fix" your incomplete *output.xml* file after execution stop with [fixml](https://bitbucket.org/robotframework/fixml). `output.xml` location for RIDE execution can be found in the very same execution log of yours (e.g. `...\appdata\local\temp\RIDEv_0yrp.d\` in my case)
2. Run `rebot` stand-alone: `rebot output.xml --log log.html --report report.html`. Rebot options description you can check using `rebot --help` (as usual)

Please also note that directory where RIDE output files are stored is temporary — exists only when RIDE is started. You will lose your output on exiting RIDE

I'm using RIDE 1.5 so maybe my answer is not valid for other versions

Answer (score 0):

In RIDE, under `Run` Tab , when you are running the scripts , you have a option, `show message log`, it will shows the runtime log.

Try this out.

Comment: A similar functionality can be Found in the Eclipse IDE for Robot Scripts RED as well. In the background this functionality is realized through the Listener interface mentioned by @Pekka.

Comment: hi, thanks for response. I am using the show message log, but its not very feasible when script is showing lot of messages, as I have to scroll through the window. Also I am facing issue, in cases when I have to "STOP" the run forceully (i case of nonresponsive device etc), in such case, once execution is stopped, no log is generated, expect for run time log. Would like to know if any option is available to generate xml/html logs in such scenario

Comment: sorry, i am not sure about that anil