# Write log file in real time in robot framework

Tags: logging, robotframework

when the robot test suite was stopped by hand, the log.html was not generated on disk.
Is there any way the log.html could be generated to disk in real time?

Answer (score 2):

> when the robot test suite was stopped by hand, the log.html was not generated on disk. Is there any way the log.html could be generated to disk in real time?

No, there is not. The underlying architecture of robot is that it keeps the logging information in an in-memory xml document while the test runs, and doesn't create the log and report files until after the test has finished and the xml document had been written to disk.

That being said, the logging *information* is available via the [listener interface](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface). Via a listener, you can have a function called after each test and after each suite, and the data provided to that function will include the pass/fail information.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this issue when debugging my custom library. Robot basically eat every stdout. You can use `from robot.api import logger` and then call `logger.console('foo')` but you are force to one unformatted `console` logger level. So I decided for completely separate logging:

**Libs/CustomLogging.py**

```
import logging
import sys


def setup_custom_logger(name):
    # https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes
    formatter = logging.Formatter(
        "%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(name)s %(message)s")
    handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.__stdout__)
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    return logger
```

**Libs/MyLib.py**

```
import CustomLogging

logger = CustomLogging.setup_custom_logger(__name__)


class MyLib:
    def __init__(self):
        logger.debug('foo')
```

Trick is here: `stream=sys.__stdout__` You have to use "original" stdout since "normal" one is eaten by Robot

I can run this and see nice/formatted log messages in console in real time when running only `MyLib.py` separately and when running Robot framework as well. To mute these, just increase loglevel in `CustomLogging.py`

Disadvantage is that this is completely separate of Robot output - nothing in `log.html` nor `output.xml`